# How can I receive sms in android?

Tags: android

I am new to android and i am using android 2.1 for some sms_receive thing: when an sms received,it won't work... I have a force close, help!

```
public class SmsReceiverActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String SHORTCODE = "55443";
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        Object[] messages = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        SmsMessage[] sms = new SmsMessage[messages.length];
        //Create messages for each incoming PDU
        for (int n = 0; n < messages.length; n++) {
            sms[n] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
        }
        for (SmsMessage msg: sms) {
            //Verify if the message came from our known sender
            if (TextUtils.equals(msg.getOriginatingAddress(), "SHORTCODE")) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Received message from the mothership: " + msg.getMessageBody(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
}
```

android manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
 <application  android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
        android:name=".SmsReceiver"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

when installing program and I want running it,I have a force close and this is my LogCat:

```
08-26 12:36:58.531: D/AndroidRuntime(700): Shutting down VM
08-26 12:36:58.531: W/dalvikvm(700): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
08-26 12:36:58.573: E/AndroidRuntime(700): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
08-26 12:36:58.621: E/AndroidRuntime(700): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.smsreceiver/com.example.smsreceiver.SmsReceiver}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.smsreceiver.SmsReceiver in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@44c07980
08-26 12:36:58.621: E/AndroidRuntime(700):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
08-26 12:36:58.621: E/AndroidRuntime(700):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
08-26 12:36:58.621: E/AndroidRuntime(700):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
08-26 12:36:58.621: E/AndroidRuntime(700):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
08-26 12:36:58.621: E/AndroidRuntime(700):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-26 12:36:58.621: E/AndroidRuntime(700):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-26 12:36:58.621: E/AndroidRuntime(700):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
08-26 12:36:58.621: E/AndroidRuntime(700):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-26 12:36:58.621: E/AndroidRuntime(700):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-26 12:36:58.621: E/AndroidRuntime(700):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
08-26 12:36:58.621: E/AndroidRuntime(700):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
08-26 12:36:58.621: E/AndroidRuntime(700):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-26 12:36:58.621: E/AndroidRuntime(700): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.smsreceiver.SmsReceiver in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@44c07980
08-26 12:36:58.621: E/AndroidRuntime(700):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
08-26 12:36:58.621: E/AndroidRuntime(700):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
08-26 12:36:58.621: E/AndroidRuntime(700):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
08-26 12:36:58.621: E/AndroidRuntime(700):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
08-26 12:36:58.621: E/AndroidRuntime(700):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2409)
08-26 12:36:58.621: E/AndroidRuntime(700):  ... 11 more
08-26 12:36:58.651: I/dalvikvm(700): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
08-26 12:36:58.651: E/dalvikvm(700): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

Comment: Please post your logcat error.

Comment: _What_ does not work? You get an error? You don't get any SMS messages?

Comment: You must read about `BroadcastReciever` first. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: You need to care about this exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do some change in your **Manifest.xml** like:

```
 <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver"> 
    <intent-filter android:priority="100">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        <action android:name="PACKAGE_NAME.android.action.broadcast"/> 
         <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>
    </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

And change your class name **SmsReceiverActivity** to **SmsReceiver** and also your class need to extend **BroadcastReceiver**.
See how to do it from here:

- [How-to-receive-sms](http://learnandroideasily.blogspot.com/2012/11/how-to-receive-sms.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need a `BroadcastReceiver` for reading SMS in your application. You can use the following.

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) intent.getExtras().get("pdus");

        SmsMessage shortMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);

        Log.i("sms received", "sms received");
        Log.i("SMS: ", shortMessage.getDisplayMessageBody());
    }
}
```

Further more you need to declare it into your application also in the following way.

```
    <receiver android:name="YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME.SmsReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Don't forget to add permissions related to SMS such as the following

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
```

Comment: Sorry Mr.Moaaviah   I have error in "Contact" and "UserPreferences" in your code,What is "Contact" and "UserPreferences"? thank alot

Comment: @maryam_mo Please check it now. There was some extra stuff which I have removed. Please change YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME with your respective package.